# Natural logarithm 2F1,hypergeometric

Tags: special-functions

I find out that $\ln (1+z) = z _2F_1(1,1,2,-z)$ and that $\ln (1-z) = -z _2F_1(1,1,2,z)$, but what is $\ln\Big( \dfrac{1+z}{1-z} \Big)$?
Is there a possibility to add two $_2F_1$?

I mean what can I do with this $\ln\Big( \dfrac{1+z}{1-z} \Big) = z(_2F_1(1,1,2,-z) + _2F_1(1,1,2,z))$ ?

Comment: What does this have to do with continued fractions?

Comment: It may help to mention the word "hypergeometric" somewhere in the question.

Comment: @Wojowu  I am using this to Gauss continued fractions so I thought that it's connected.

Comment: $\ln\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right)=2\,{\rm arctanh}\, z$ --- why bother with hypergeometric functions?

Comment: @CarloBeenakker I need hypergeometric functions to use Gauss continued fraction in order to do some numerical tests

Answer (score 1):

$$
\log\left(\frac{1+z}{1-z}\right) = 2 z \;{}_2F_1\left(\frac{1}{2},1;\frac{3}{2};z^2\right)
$$

Comment: Thank you.
So could you tell me which the proper forum is for questions like that?
And how did you get that formula?

Comment: And how did you get yours? Hypergeometric functions are just funny power series expansions with the ratios of terms given by some rational functions of $k$ (with real roots and poles, unless you don't mind complex parameters) times the argument. So, you should just make sure that the non-zero coefficients form an arithmetic progressions and the ratios of the consecutive coefficients are rational functions of $k$. In your cases the coefficients themselves are rational functions of $k$, so the only headache is to not forget to cancel the"historical" $(k+1)$ when listing the parameters...